# Web Scraper using Python to download .png Images from .html webpage located on my C:/ drive locally to local folder

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a python script that imports beautiful soup, requests, and `urllib.request` APIs to fetch images from the address `https://www.example.com/image.jpg` and it works OK, listing them in my documents folder well numbered.

I have tried varies methods listed here but none seem to have helped, on google the solution were revolving around getting tags.

The question is how to script it to fetch images from my example.html sitting on my `C:/` drive using the mentioned python script, where the browser am using is Opera and the HTML URL is `file:///C:/Users/folder/folder/Desktop/folder/example.html`, on the web address bar.

Here is the python script,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import requests

    # setting URL destination 
    url = "file:///C:/Users/folder/folder/Desktop/folder/example.html"
    
    # retrieving HTML payload from the website
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    # using BeautifulSoup to parse the response object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    
    # finding Post images in the soup
    images = soup.find_all("png", attrs={"alt":"Post image"})
    
    # downloading images
    number = 0
    for image in images:
        print(image["src"])
        image_src = image["src"]
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_src, str(number))
        number += 1
```

Comment: You may want to serve that `folder` with an HTTP server (Python's built-in `python -m http.server` will be a good start) so you don't need to work with `file://` URLs at all.

Comment: Salutations @AKX, am a noobie your assistance iis well recieved but i simply dont know how to go about your well thought solution

Comment: In your `C:/Users/folder/folder/Desktop/folder` directory, run `python -m http.server`. This will expose that directory as `http://localhost:8000`, so you can point your script to `http://localhost:8000/example.html` instead. Making your example work for `file://` URLs will be more involved and likely not necessary anyway.

Comment: `soup.find_all("png"` will find `<png />` tags, which is not a standard html tag name. You should presumably look for `<img />` instead. `find_all("img"`

Comment: @AKX its showig Directory listing for / desktop.ini
My Music/
My Pictures/
My Videos/
script.py
*web.py
ow how to point the script web.py to http://localhost:8000/example.html

Comment: @Haken Lid much appreciative for the assistance tried that also no avail

Comment: @msiplayer `url = "http://localhost:8000/example.html"` in your script... :)

Comment: @AKX ::1 - - [02/Nov/2021 13:57:35] "GET /example.html HTTP/1.1" 200 - yet the images seem not to show n desired folder

Comment: And your script prints those `image["src"]`s? :)

Comment: @AKX my images are in .png format by the way

Comment: @AKX no my script doesn't print those image source, the only thing I've changed is the url, apart from that the script looks exactly as the question above

Comment: Then make sure your `example.html` contains matching tags. (`<png alt="Post image" src="...">`? :) )

Comment: @AKX yes have checked all matching tags plus this all shows up ::1 - - [02/Nov/2021 14:13:57] "GET /body50.png HTTP/1.1" 200 - from print(image["src"])

Comment: So then your script evidently is doing things. :)

Comment: Oh Yes...@AKX but no image scrapping to desired folder apparently